# How can I trace the calls of a java application that I have built and run in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to be able to see what classes, methods get called when I execute various scenarios for a java application that I'm running in eclipse.  Is there a way for me doing this without setting breakpoints and without putting a bunch of system.out.println in the code.  I'd just like to see a "call tree" and then be able to run through another scenario and see a different call tree.  I'm trying to understand this code without benefit of any documentation.

Comment: Good questions tend to be asked before, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025681/call-trace-in-java