# Flow execution in Ejb project in java

Tags: java, ejb

Hi am working on very very old projects which contain 10 to 15 dependencies **am very curious to know any tool or some utility**  to track flow execution of java class,method,lines,return type,get query executed while operation ..etc

**for example:
if am calling soap request from SoapUI its goes into @WebService() and flow goes on..**

[How do I trace methods calls in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382231/how-do-i-trace-methods-calls-in-java) i have seen this link not sure how to incorporate and execute in existing project am doing manual job right now by debug with eclipse.kindly help on if way to write code or tool which i can see executions

Answer (score 0):

JPDA.  any decent IDE will connect to your container via JDPA protocol and allow you to debug from inside the container.  you have to configure the container using some configuration switches (which get passed onto the JVM at startup time).  check the documentation for you app server for how it prefers to be configured for JPDA.