# How to find when the method(in a .class which we don't have access to source code) get invoked by some other class

Tags: java

How to find when the method(in a .class which we dont have access to source code) get invoked by some other class & is there any possibility to change the method argument using java

Comment: Reflection might be what you're looking for: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: This post could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382231/how-do-i-trace-methods-calls-in-java/29384646